# Python Mechanize Submit Failure due to 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0'

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I'm trying to log into Yahoo with Python 2.7 Mechanize. I'm running into an error where I can't encode the results properly. Has anyone run into this?

```
import platform
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import mechanize
import cookielib
import sys  

br = mechanize.Browser()

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)


br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
print'opening'
response = br.open('https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us')
print response.geturl()
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = 'fakeusername'
response = br.submit()
print response.geturl()
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['password'] = 'fakepassword'
response = br.submit()
print response.geturl()
```

I'm getting the error code on the password submit: `br.form['password'] = 'fakepassword'
    response = br.submit()`

```
C:\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.pyc in urlencode(query, doseq)
   1345         for k, v in query:
   1346             k = quote_plus(str(k))
-> 1347             v = quote_plus(str(v))
   1348             l.append(k + '=' + v)
   1349     else:


 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The extended Ascii character for `A0` is the "non-breaking space", you might want to dive a little deeper into what values are in your variables around line 1347

Comment: More pertinently, the **Unicode** code-point A0 represents a non-breaking space, so it's likely you have one or more in your data.

Comment: Ah yes, because `u` prefixed on the string means Unicode. Almost forgot that

Comment: The difficulty is that the submit does some magic behind the scenes, which I can't quit clean up. The urllib.pyc is failing here.